# Fitting Naive Bayes on Floating Point Data Values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-analysis

I want to fit Gaussian Naive Bayes on data values with floating point, and the code I'm using is this:

```
array1 = np.array([[2,2],[3,2]]) 
array2 = np.array([0.3,3])

clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(array1,array2)
```

But, I get an error saying:

> ValueError("Unknown label type: %s" % repr(ys))
>   ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([ 0.3,  3. ]),)

How can I get around the issue without using a different naive bayes module than the one provided by Sklearn?

Answer (score 2):

You using `array2` as your target labels.

`GaussianNB()` is a classifier, so target labels must be integers.(in your case 0.3 is float)

If your labels are real numbers, consider using Regression.